# Convert R to Javascript for highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

Im looking to convert an R Script to JavaScript so I can dynamically change a HightCharts.js plot. However, I don't how to approach writing a JavaScript function to simulate the rnorm() function in R. Any advice about tackling an issue like this is greatly appreciated.

this is the R code..

```
## create random normal variables with correct mean and standard deviations 

RHT <- round(rnorm(50, mean= HTot, sd= HtX))
RAT <- round(rnorm(50, mean= ATot , sd= AtX))

## combine data 

ranScor <- cbind(RHT,RAT)
ranScor <- data.frame(ranScor)

### plotting simple line graph

plot(RHT,type="b", col= "blue", lwd=1, ylim=c(min(ranScor),max(ranScor)),xlab="Game Simulations",ylab="Team Score", main="Random Score Generator", sub="Indianapolis Colts @ Denver Broncos")
lines(RAT, type="b", col="red",lwd=1)
legend("topleft",legend=c("HomeTeam","AwayTeam"),lty=1,col=c("blue","red"),lwd=2,cex=.7)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform

Comment: you can peruse the R source for standard normal, there are a few algorithms, https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/snorm.c

Comment: [highchartR](https://github.com/jcizel/highchartR)

Comment: Why you cannot use a native javascript instead of converting R into JS ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the equation of the normal distribution? Generate your x and y coordinates and then draw the normal curve:

```
function y(x, sd, mean) {
   return Math.pow(Math.E,-Math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*Math.pow(1, 2)))/(sd*Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI));
}
```